# Material Angular card display

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have a gallery of images and I would like to display them in a polaroid card-based system spanning multiple rows and columns. The problem I'm facing relates to the layout of the image. When images are both portrait and landscape, the mat-card attribute for the landscape ones gets bloated up to match the size of the portrait ones. How can I have a naturally filling system where the mat-card is adaptable to the width/height ratio of the image?

HTML:

```html
    <div fxLayout="row">
        <div layout="column">
            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlexOffset="1" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="2rem" class="mat-elevation-z0" *ngIf="postcards != null">
                <mat-card *ngFor="let postcard of postcards let index = index" >
                        <img mat-card-image src="{{postcard.img}}" alt="{{postcard.postcard_id}}" class="postcards" (click)="display_postcard(index)">
                </mat-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .postcards {
        max-width: 320px;
    }
```

Current view:
[image: You can see how the container for each landscape card gets expanded to match the height of the portrait one (not what I would like to achieve)]

And this is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `fxLayoutAlign` property.

Try to add `fxLayoutAlign="start start"` to your `div` like this:

```
<div fxFlex="100" fxFlexOffset="1" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="2rem" fxLayoutAlign="start start" class="mat-elevation-z0" *ngIf="postcards != null">
```

**P.S.** Check out [Flex-Layout Demo](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) if you want to play around with different options.

Comment: Thanks! It halfway there! This renders the mat-card size-appropriate to the image however, it does not put two landscape images in the same column. I'm starting to believe that might not be possible :/

Comment: It seems that all your cards have the same width. Assuming that I suggest you try `fxLayout="column"` on the same div and see if you're getting closer. Let me know if it helped

Comment: Sadly, this makes the whole page into a single column :(

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try masonry or isotope to help fill in the gaps, both have npm packages in dev:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-isotope

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-masonry

Comment: I don't know why I thought this would be achievable without the use of more libraries, but I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks for the suggestions, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know my respond will be see as weird but i think that float left might be you are searching for ( yeah i hate float myself )

But if you get rid of all the flex stuff of your example and add margin directly on mat-card

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z0" *ngIf="postcards != null">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let postcard of postcards let index = index" >
              <img mat-card-image src="{{postcard.img}}" alt="{{postcard.postcard_id}}" class="postcards" (click)="display_postcard(index)">
      </mat-card>
</div>



mat-card {
   margin: 1rem;
   float: left;
}
```

Your card will try to fit in the available space. But of course this will not be a perfect match for all cases. But i think its the better css-only solution you can found.